# Which Xamarin project type to choose for a material design Android app?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Which Xamarin project type do I choose if I want to build a top-notch material design Android app?

1. **Xamarin.Android or Cross-Platform Xamarin App?**

   I'd prefer a "cross-platform" app since I want to target iOS later, but if there is something missing then I'd prefer going with Xamarin.Android and think about code sharing later.

[image: cross platform]

2. **Xamarin.Forms or manually defining android UI in XML?**

   Does a [Xamarin.Forms](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/) app include all the fine-grained control needed for producing top-notch "material design" apps?

   Are such things possible with Xamarin.Forms?

[image: samples]

Comment: If your application is complex and you would like for design to be polished on every platform - I'd say go with native android app (so, not with xamarin forms). That's what I always do unless app is very simple.

Comment: If based on your screenshot, you can do all of that in X.Forms. The *tricky* part is putting edit/search component on top of the Navigation Bar. See https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84526/titleview-for-pages , this isn't possible in X.Forms now - you have to do custom renderer for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chose cross-platform or android specific. It does not matter at this point as you will be able to switch to material design afterwards.

You will just have to configure your android app as described in this [link](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/).

Which means:
Setting the colors (you can do without if you set your colors directly)
**Resources/values/colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
      <color name="primary">#2196F3</color>
      <color name="primaryDark">#1976D2</color>
      <color name="accent">#FFC107</color>
      <color name="window_background">#F5F5F5</color>
    </resources>
```

Setting your style
**Resources/values/style.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
      <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
      </style>
      <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
      </style>
    </resources>
```

**Resources/values-v21/style.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
      <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
        <!--If you are using MasterDetailPage you will want to set these, else you can leave them out-->
        <!--<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
      </style>
    </resources>
```

Add this in **Properties/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application android:label="AppName" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Customizing the Toolbar and Tabs
**Resources/layout/tabs.axml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

**Resources/layout/toolbar.axml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

And then in your main activity, you inherit from `FormsAppCompatActivity`

and you modify your oncreate override like this

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
    FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create a new Xamarin Forms prj, your Android prj should be ready for [Material Design](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/)

First, set your Target framework to Android 6.0 or higher.

Then you should apply new thems and customize toolbars and tabs.

The last is to change MainActivity to

```
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
```

and

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
    FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In "Visual C#" > "Cross-Platform" choose "Blank Xaml App"

You can see two option like this Blank Xaml App(Xamarin.Forms Portable) and Blank Xaml App(Xamarin.Forms Shared). You can choose one of them as per your project requirement. This both option create android app project with material design.